# Threading in python flask server

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create a thread in a flask server and it just doesnt seem to be firing. I am not getting any errors either. Here is my code:

```
t = Thread(target=pourDrink, args=(VALID_BCM_PIN_NUMBERS[0],float(j[1]), mc, total,))
print "turning on 1"
t.start
```

and what I'm calling:

```
def pourDrink(drink, amount, mc, total):
    # some long running task here
    data = pin_update(drink, 0)
    print "sleeping amount " + str(amount)
    time.sleep(float(amount))
```

The thing is it never even prints out the "sleeping amount" Is there something I am doing wrong?
Let me know if I need to provide more info or code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **call** the `Thread.start` method:

```
t.start()
```

Just referencing it is not enough.

Comment: That was it, thanks I didnt realize the difference.